# How can i use_weighted_increment for null data with mdx query

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, updates

When I try to update cube data with `use_weighted_increment`, sometimes its giving error for null data.

Is there any thing like slq's `isnull()`?
Or how can I update empty cell with weighted_increment?

```
UPDATE [Quota]
SET (
      [Dimension1].[Dim1 Attribute1].[Attribute1 Dim1].&[1], //AG1
      [DataVersion].[Version].&[1], //Quota
      [Dimension2].[Dim2 Parent Member].&[1], //Product 1
      [Dimension3].[Dim3 Parent Member].&[-1], //Undefined
      [Dimension4].[Dim4 Parent Member].&[-1], //Undefined
      [Dimension5].[Dim5 Parent Member].&[-1], //Undefined      
      [Measures].[Amount Implicit]
    ) = 6000
    USE_WEIGHTED_INCREMENT
```

Answer (score 0):

0 can be treated like null in `MDX`.
Therefore you can use "= 0" to test if null.

In this article (http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2005/06/30/how-to-check-if-cell-is-empty-in-mdx.aspx) by Mosha Pasumansky (one of the creators of mdx) he says that the following:

> The first one
>
> IIF(b = 0, NULL, a/b)
>
> Is actually the most correct one.